# how to manipulate google chart to take the random legends in haxis

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

I am using google charts to plot area cahrt using dynamic data, the number of data will be dynamic, the data my contain one month data or different months data, bu the legend in the haxis should be nicely randomly taken and show. with my current program it shows only one lagend at the begining that too shows only when we hover the legend, the legend should be shown intelegenlty based on the number of data and based on number of months data.

For eg i used same month data with differnet dates, but the actuall requirement the data may for one month or for differnet months

```js
        google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages': ['corechart']
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var mydata = [
                ['Date', 'value'],
                [
                    "1/Apr/2017",
                    1
                ],
                [
                    "2/Apr/2017",
                    2
                ],
                [
                    "3/Apr/2017",
                    3
                ],
                [
                    "4/Apr/2017",
                    4
                ],
                [
                    "5/Apr/2017",
                    5
                ],
                [
                    "6/Apr/2017",
                    6
                ],
                [
                    "7/Apr/2017",
                    7
                ],
                [
                    "8/Apr/2017",
                    8
                ],
                [
                    "9/Apr/2017",
                    9
                ],
                [
                    "10/Apr/2017",
                    10
                ],
                [
                    "11/Apr/2017",
                    11
                ],
                [
                    "12/Apr/2017",
                    12
                ],
                [
                    "13/Apr/2017",
                    13
                ],
                [
                    "14/Apr/2017",
                    14
                ],
                [
                    "15/Apr/2017",
                    15
                ],
                [
                    "16/Apr/2017",
                    16
                ],
                [
                    "17/Apr/2017",
                    17
                ],
                [
                    "18/Apr/2017",
                    18
                ],
                [
                    "19/Apr/2017",
                    19
                ],
                [
                    "20/Apr/2017",
                    20
                ],
                [
                    "21/Apr/2017",
                    21
                ],
                [
                    "22/Apr/2017",
                    22
                ],
                [
                    "23/Apr/2017",
                    23
                ],
                [
                    "24/Apr/2017",
                    24
                ],
                [
                    "25/Apr/2017",
                    25
                ],
                [
                    "26/Apr/2017",
                    26
                ],
                [
                    "27/Apr/2017",
                    27
                ],
                [
                    "28/Apr/2017",
                    28
                ],
                [
                    "29/Apr/2017",
                    29
                ],
                [
                    "30/Apr/2017",
                    30
                ]

            ];
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(mydata);



            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([{
                type: 'date',
                label: 'Date',
                calc: function (dt, row) {
                    return new Date(dt.getValue(row, 0));
                }
            }, 1]);
            data = view.toDataTable();
            data.sort([{
                column: 0
            }]);
            function primeFactors( n)
            {
                x=[]
                // Print the number of 2s that divide n
                while (n%2 == 0)
                {        x.push( 2);
                    n = n/2;
                }
            
                // n must be odd at this point.  So we can skip 
                // one element (Note i = i +2)
                for (var i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i = i+2)
                {        // While i divides n, print i and divide n
                    while (n%i == 0)
                    {
                        x.push(i);
                        n = n/i;
                    }
                } 
                if (n > 2)
                x.push( n);
                return x;
            }
            function getDatatchuma() {
                var x = [] 
                    var last =primeFactors(data.og.length );
                    
                    if(last.length===1)
                    last=primeFactors(data.og.length-1); 
                    last =last[last.length-1];
                    var lM="";
                    var lY="";
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.og.length; i+=last) { 

                        if (lM=== data.og[i].c[0].v.getMonth() &&
                         lY=== data.og[i].c[0].v.getFullYear())   
                            continue;
                        lM=data.og[i].c[0].v.getMonth() 
                        lY=data.og[i].c[0].v.getFullYear();
                        x.push(data.og[i].c[0].v);
                    }
                    console.log(x);
                    if(x.length<5){
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.og.length; i+=last) { 
                            lM=data.og[i].c[0].v.getMonth() 
                        lY=data.og[i].c[0].v.getFullYear();
                        x.push(data.og[i].c[0].v);
                        }
                    }
               
                return x;
            }

            var options = {
                chartArea: {
                    bottom: 56
                },
                title: 'Company Performance',
                hAxis: {
                    format: data.og[0].c[0].v.getMonth() === data.og[data.og.length - 1].c[0].v.getMonth() &&
                        data.og[0].c[0].v.getFullYear() === data.og[data.og.length - 1].c[0].v.getFullYear() ?
                        "dd-MMM" : 'MMM-yy',
                    titleTextStyle: {
                        color: '#333'
                    },
                    ticks: getDatatchuma(),
                },
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom'
                },
                
                pointSize: 5,
                dataOpacity: 0.5,
                vAxis: {
                    scaleType: 'log',
             /*       viewWindow: {
              max:500,
              min:10
            }*/
                    minValue: data.og[0].c[1].v
                }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to determine if there is more than one month of data,
we can use data table method --> `getColumnRange`

`getColumnRange` will return an object with properties for `min` and `max` values of the column

so if the `min` & `max` values have the same month, we can use format --> `'dd-MMM'`
otherwise --> `'MMM-yy'`

```
var hAxisFormat;
var xRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
if (xRange.min.getMonth() === xRange.max.getMonth()) {
  hAxisFormat = 'dd-MMM';
} else {
  hAxisFormat = 'MMM-yy';
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var mydata = [
      ['Date', 'value'],
      [
        "1/Apr/2017",
        1
      ],
      [
        "2/Apr/2017",
        2
      ],
      [
        "3/Apr/2017",
        3
      ],
      [
        "4/Apr/2017",
        4
      ],
      [
        "5/Apr/2017",
        5
      ],
      [
        "6/Apr/2017",
        6
      ],
      [
        "7/Apr/2017",
        7
      ],
      [
        "8/Apr/2017",
        8
      ],
      [
        "9/Apr/2017",
        9
      ],
      [
        "10/Apr/2017",
        10
      ],
      [
        "11/Apr/2017",
        11
      ],
      [
        "12/Apr/2017",
        12
      ],
      [
        "13/Apr/2017",
        13
      ],
      [
        "14/Apr/2017",
        14
      ],
      [
        "15/Apr/2017",
        15
      ],
      [
        "16/Apr/2017",
        16
      ],
      [
        "17/Apr/2017",
        17
      ],
      [
        "18/Apr/2017",
        18
      ],
      [
        "19/Apr/2017",
        19
      ],
      [
        "20/Apr/2017",
        20
      ],
      [
        "21/Apr/2017",
        21
      ],
      [
        "22/Apr/2017",
        22
      ],
      [
        "23/Apr/2017",
        23
      ],
      [
        "24/Apr/2017",
        24
      ],
      [
        "25/Apr/2017",
        25
      ],
      [
        "26/Apr/2017",
        26
      ],
      [
        "27/Apr/2017",
        27
      ],
      [
        "28/Apr/2017",
        28
      ],
      [
        "29/Apr/2017",
        29
      ],
      [
        "30/Apr/2017",
        30
      ]

  ];
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(mydata);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([{
    type: 'date',
    label: 'Date',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        return new Date(dt.getValue(row, 0));
    }
  }, 1]);
  data = view.toDataTable();
  data.sort([{
    column: 0
  }]);

  var hAxisFormat;
  var xRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
  if (xRange.min.getMonth() === xRange.max.getMonth()) {
    hAxisFormat = 'dd-MMM';
  } else {
    hAxisFormat = 'MMM-yy';
  }

  var yRange = data.getColumnRange(1);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 56
    },
    title: 'Company Performance',
    hAxis: {
      format: hAxisFormat,
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#333'
      }
    },
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    pointSize: 5,
    dataOpacity: 0.5,
    vAxis: {
      scaleType: 'log',
      minValue: yRange.min
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Working fine, as per the requirement